# Problem with data received from MQTT to Signal R

Tags: javascript, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

This is the code related to javescript and signalr and data is received from MQTT and is working partially -

The data for same network is getting cleared with old data and getting reflected with new data but when data is sent for other networks, the data disppears or is cleared and this is the problem

```
// Object to store unique camera IDs for each network
let uniqueCameraIds = {};

// Mapping for camera IDs to image paths
let cameraImagePaths = {};

// Object to store network-specific data
let networkData = {};

let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub/status")
    .build();

connection.start()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("SignalR connected");

        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message, imgPaths) => {
            console.log("Received data from SignalR:", message);

            try {
                let data = typeof message === 'string' ? JSON.parse(message) : message;
                let msgTypes = data.msg_content.split(":");

                if (msgTypes[0] === 'm') {
                    handleObjectMessage(data, imgPaths);
                } else if (msgTypes[0] === 'h') {
                    handleHeartbeatMessage(data);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error parsing JSON or extracting values:", error);
            }
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error starting SignalR connection:", err.toString());
    });

function handleObjectMessage(data, imgPaths) {
    let msgContent = data.msg_content.slice(2);
    let zoneDataArray = msgContent.split('|');

    // Extract and log the address
    let receivedAddress = `${data.network_add}.${data.node_add}`;
    console.log("Received address:", receivedAddress);

    // Check if the networkData object exists for the received network
    if (!networkData[receivedAddress]) {
        console.log(`Initializing data for network: ${receivedAddress}`);
        networkData[receivedAddress] = {
            uniqueCameraIds: [],
            cameraImagePaths: {},
            currentNetworkAddress: receivedAddress, // Store the current network address
            isFirstTime: true // isFirstTime is set to true during initialization
        };
    }

    // Clear old data if it's not the first time and the received network matches the current network
    if (!networkData[receivedAddress].isFirstTime && receivedAddress === networkData[receivedAddress].currentNetworkAddress) {
        console.log(`Clearing old data for network: ${receivedAddress}`);
        console.log("Current network address:", networkData[receivedAddress].currentNetworkAddress);
        console.log("isFirstTime:", networkData[receivedAddress].isFirstTime);

        // Clear data only for the current network
        clearDataForNetwork(receivedAddress);
        console.log("After clearing old data. Current network address:", networkData[receivedAddress].currentNetworkAddress);
    }

    // Retain data for cameras in the same network
    zoneDataArray.forEach(zoneData => {
        let cameraId = zoneData.split(',')[0];

        // Check if the cameraId is already in the uniqueCameraIds array
        if (!networkData[receivedAddress].uniqueCameraIds.includes(cameraId)) {
            networkData[receivedAddress].uniqueCameraIds.push(cameraId);
        }
    });

    imgPaths.forEach(imgPath => {
        Object.keys(imgPath).forEach(cameraId => {
            networkData[receivedAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId] = imgPath[cameraId];
        });
    });

    // Update the current network address
    networkData[receivedAddress].currentNetworkAddress = receivedAddress;
    networkData[receivedAddress].isFirstTime = false;

    // Update the camera table only if the corresponding HTML element exists
    let dashboardElement = document.getElementById(`dashboard${receivedAddress}`);
    if (dashboardElement !== null) {
        console.log(`Received address ${receivedAddress} exists in the HTML model.`);
        updateCameraTable(zoneDataArray, data, receivedAddress);
    } else {
        console.warn(`Received address ${receivedAddress} and id do not match Error.`);
    }
}

function clearDataForNetwork(networkAddress) {
    networkData[networkAddress].uniqueCameraIds.forEach((cameraId) => {
        clearTableForCamera(networkAddress, cameraId);
    });

    // Reset the networkData object for the current network
    networkData[networkAddress].uniqueCameraIds = [];
    networkData[networkAddress].cameraImagePaths = {};
}

function updateCameraTable(zoneDataArray, data, receivedAddress) {
    zoneDataArray.forEach((zoneData) => {
        let values = zoneData.split(',');

        let cameraId = values[0];
        let zoneId = values[1];
        let peopleCount = values[2];
        let carCount = values[3];
        let truckCount = values[4];
        let motorcycleCount = values[5];
        let miscCount = values[6];

        console.log("Extracted values:", receivedAddress, data.msg_id, cameraId, zoneId, peopleCount, carCount, truckCount, motorcycleCount, miscCount);

        if (cameraId === null || cameraId === undefined) {
            console.error("Camera ID is null or undefined. Handle this condition as needed.");
            return;
        }

        let formattedZoneId = `Zone${zoneId.replace('|', '_')}`;

        let tableCell = $(`#tableZone${cameraId} [data-zone="${formattedZoneId}"]`);

        if (tableCell.find('.people').text() === '-') {
            tableCell.find('.people').text(` ${peopleCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.car').text(` ${carCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.truck').text(` ${truckCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.bike').text(` ${motorcycleCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.misc').text(` ${miscCount}`);
        }

        if (networkData[receivedAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId]) {
            $(`#ImageCard${cameraId} .image-card`).attr('src', networkData[receivedAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId]);
            console.log(`Image path for camera ${cameraId}: ${networkData[receivedAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId]}`);
        }
    });
}

function handleHeartbeatMessage(data) {
    // TODO: get the element of ONLINE-OFFLINE and change the text when heartbeat is received
    let spanElement = document.getElementById(`d-${data.network_add}.${data.node_add}`);
    console.log("found span element");
}

function clearTableForCamera(networkAddress, cameraId) {
    $(`#tableZone${cameraId} [data-zone] td:not(:first-child)`).text('-');
}
```

The data for same network is getting cleared with old data and getting reflected with new data but when data for other networks disppears or is cleared and this is the problem

Comment: Hi Surya, could you try my answer below ?  Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

My tweak to the network data handling logic ensures that old data for that network is only cleared when new data is received for the same network address. The purpose of this is to avoid data from different networks interfering with each other.

**Here is the sample code**

```
// Object to store unique camera IDs for each network
let uniqueCameraIds = {};

// Mapping for camera IDs to image paths
let cameraImagePaths = {};

// Object to store network-specific data
let networkData = {};

let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hub/status")
    .build();

connection.start()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("SignalR connected");

        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message, imgPaths) => {
            console.log("Received data from SignalR:", message);

            try {
                let data = typeof message === 'string' ? JSON.parse(message) : message;
                let msgTypes = data.msg_content.split(":");

                if (msgTypes[0] === 'm') {
                    handleObjectMessage(data, imgPaths);
                } else if (msgTypes[0] === 'h') {
                    handleHeartbeatMessage(data);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error parsing JSON or extracting values:", error);
            }
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error starting SignalR connection:", err.toString());
    });

function handleObjectMessage(data, imgPaths) {
    let msgContent = data.msg_content.slice(2);
    let zoneDataArray = msgContent.split('|');
    // Extract and log the address
    let receivedAddress = `${data.network_add}.${data.node_add}`;
    console.log("Received address:", receivedAddress);

    // Check if the networkData object exists for the received network
    if (!networkData[receivedAddress]) {
        console.log(`Initializing data for network: ${receivedAddress}`);
        networkData[receivedAddress] = {
            uniqueCameraIds: [],
            cameraImagePaths: {},
            currentNetworkAddress: receivedAddress, // Store the current network address
            isFirstTime: true // isFirstTime is set to true during initialization
        };
    } else {
        if (receivedAddress === networkData[receivedAddress].currentNetworkAddress) {
            clearDataForNetwork(receivedAddress);
        }
    }

    // Update the current network address
    networkData[receivedAddress].currentNetworkAddress = receivedAddress;
    updateNetworkData(receivedAddress, zoneDataArray, imgPaths);

    let dashboardElement = document.getElementById(`dashboard${receivedAddress}`);
    if (dashboardElement !== null) {
        updateCameraTable(zoneDataArray, data, receivedAddress);
    } else {
        console.warn(`Dashboard element for address ${receivedAddress} not found.`);
    }
}

function clearDataForNetwork(networkAddress) {
    if (networkData[networkAddress]) {
        networkData[networkAddress].uniqueCameraIds.forEach((cameraId) => {
            clearTableForCamera(networkAddress, cameraId);
        });
        // Reset the networkData object for the current network
        networkData[networkAddress].uniqueCameraIds = [];
        networkData[networkAddress].cameraImagePaths = {};
    }
}


function updateNetworkData(networkAddress, zoneDataArray, imgPaths) {
    zoneDataArray.forEach(zoneData => {
        let cameraId = zoneData.split(',')[0];
        // Check if the cameraId is already in the uniqueCameraIds array
        if (!networkData[networkAddress].uniqueCameraIds.includes(cameraId)) {
            networkData[networkAddress].uniqueCameraIds.push(cameraId);
        }
    });

    imgPaths.forEach(imgPath => {
        Object.keys(imgPath).forEach(cameraId => {
            networkData[networkAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId] = imgPath[cameraId];
        });
    });

    networkData[networkAddress].isFirstTime = false;
}

function updateCameraTable(zoneDataArray, data, receivedAddress) {
     zoneDataArray.forEach((zoneData) => {
        let values = zoneData.split(',');

        let cameraId = values[0];
        let zoneId = values[1];
        let peopleCount = values[2];
        let carCount = values[3];
        let truckCount = values[4];
        let motorcycleCount = values[5];
        let miscCount = values[6];

        console.log("Extracted values:", receivedAddress, data.msg_id, cameraId, zoneId, peopleCount, carCount, truckCount, motorcycleCount, miscCount);

        if (cameraId === null || cameraId === undefined) {
            console.error("Camera ID is null or undefined. Handle this condition as needed.");
            return;
        }

        let formattedZoneId = `Zone${zoneId.replace('|', '_')}`;

        let tableCell = $(`#tableZone${cameraId} [data-zone="${formattedZoneId}"]`);

        if (tableCell.find('.people').text() === '-') {
            tableCell.find('.people').text(` ${peopleCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.car').text(` ${carCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.truck').text(` ${truckCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.bike').text(` ${motorcycleCount}`);
            tableCell.find('.misc').text(` ${miscCount}`);
        }

        if (networkData[receivedAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId]) {
            $(`#ImageCard${cameraId} .image-card`).attr('src', networkData[receivedAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId]);
            console.log(`Image path for camera ${cameraId}: ${networkData[receivedAddress].cameraImagePaths[cameraId]}`);
        }
    });
}

function handleHeartbeatMessage(data) {
    // TODO: get the element of ONLINE-OFFLINE and change the text when heartbeat is received
    let spanElement = document.getElementById(`d-${data.network_add}.${data.node_add}`);
    console.log("found span element");
}

function clearTableForCamera(networkAddress, cameraId) {
    $(`#tableZone${cameraId} [data-zone] td:not(:first-child)`).text('-');
}
```